# How to handle optional body with PUT or DELETE HTTP Requests (in a Play Application)?

Tags: rest, api, http, playframework-2.0, api-design

`reservation` is a resource with 4 fields They are `id`, `dataCenter`, `startDate`, `endDate`

I wish to handle both types of requests:

1. In which there is a body with a list of dataCenters
2. In which they don't send a body (in this case I will perform the operation on all dataCenters which are present in the database).

Without body:

`PUT /reservation/123/end`

`DELETE /reservation/123`

With body:

`PUT /reservation/123/end`

```
{
    "dataCenters": ["AMS", "CLT"]
}
```

`DELETE /reservation`

```
{
    "dataCenters": ["AMS", "CLT"]
}
```

The problem being the server expects the body to be a valid JSON even when there is no body (which isn't the case when the body is empty). What would be the best way to handle this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one possible solution, not a clean one, but works.

For PUT

```
    Json
    .fromJson[OptionalDatacenters](request.body.asJson.getOrElse(JsArray()))
    .getOrElse(OptionalDatacenters(None))
    .dataCenters
```

For DELETE

```
Action.async(parse.raw) { request =>
  val dataCenters =
    request.body
      .asBytes()
      .map(
        bytes =>
          if (bytes.size > 1) Json.parse(bytes.toArray).as[OptionalDatacenters]
          else OptionalDatacenters(None)
      )
      .getOrElse(OptionalDatacenters(None))
      .dataCenters
```